# What is wrong with this Angular model?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My view:

```
block content
  .container-fluid(ng-controller='SignUpController')
    .panel.panel-default
      .panel-heading
        .panel-title
          h3 Sign Up
      .panel-body
        #signupbox.mainbox.col-md-6.col-md-offset-3.col-sm-8.col-sm-offset-2
          form#signupform.form-horizontal(role='form')
            .form-group(style='padding-top:30px')
              label.col-md-3.control-label(for='firstname') First Name
              .col-md-9
                input.form-control(type='text', ng-model='user.first_name', placeholder='First Name')
            .form-group
              label.col-md-3.control-label(for='lastname') Last Name
              .col-md-9
            input.form-control(type='text', ng-model='user.last_name', placeholder='Last Name')
```

At the end of the above code, I have a button that executes 'register()'.

My controller would be:

```
var app = window.angular.module('appname', [])

app.controller('SignUpController', function ($scope, User) {
  $scope.newUser = function () {
    $scope.user = new User({
      first_name: user.first_name
      last_name: user.last_name
      email: user.email
      company: user.company
      industry: user.industry
      phone_number: user.phone_number
      password: user.password
      source: user.source
    })

  }

  $scope.register = function () {
  //code
    $scope.user.$save().then(function () {$scope.newUser})
  }
```

And my model:

```
 var mongoose = require('mongoose')
 var Schema = mongoose.Schema

 var db = require('../config/db')

 var UserSchema = new Schema({
   first_name: String,
   last_name: String,
   email: String,
   company: String,
   industry: String,
   phone_number: String,
   password: String,
   source: String
 })

 var User = db.model('User', UserSchema)

 module.exports = User
```

My DB config:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise
var db = mongoose.connect(process.env.DB_CONN)
module.exports = db
```

When I click on the button that executes register(), nothing happens? I would like to add that user to my model.

Comment: You are confusing client side code with server side code unless you have an angular service `User` not shown

Comment: I do not have a service like that.

Comment: Mongoose is server side... not client side. What errors are thrown in browser console?

Comment: Literally nothing